# How do I fix too many redirection errors in an ASP.NET Core application with Windows authentication?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 application with an [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) core which uses Windows authentication.

When I run the application locally using the IIS Express edition or locally using IIS server, it runs fine. The same goes when I deploy it to our [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 IIS servers and when I run it by surfing to the servers, either by the server name or by using the site host header.

The problem starts when I asked other users to access the application and they receive the error too many redirections.

I tried enabling the anonymous authentication in IIS.

I tried to disable all the HTTPS enforcements in my startup.cs file like
`app.UseHsts()` and `app.UseHttpsRedirection()`.

Here is my startup.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GatePassSystem.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;


namespace GatePassSystem
{
    public class RouteDataRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
    {
        public int IndexOfCulture;
        public int IndexofUICulture;

        public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

            string culture = null;
            string uiCulture = null;

            var twoLetterCultureName = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/')[IndexOfCulture]?.ToString();
            var twoLetterUICultureName = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/')[IndexofUICulture]?.ToString();

            if (twoLetterCultureName == "he")
                culture = "he-IL";
            else if (twoLetterCultureName == "en")
                culture = uiCulture = "en-US";

            if (twoLetterUICultureName == "he")
                culture = "he-IL";
            else if (twoLetterUICultureName == "en")
                culture = uiCulture = "en-US";

            if (culture == null && uiCulture == null)
                return NullProviderCultureResult;

            if (culture != null && uiCulture == null)
                uiCulture = culture;

            if (culture == null && uiCulture != null)
                culture = uiCulture;

            var providerResultCulture = new ProviderCultureResult(culture, uiCulture);

            return Task.FromResult(providerResultCulture);
        }
    }


    public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (!values.ContainsKey("culture"))
                return false;

            var culture = values["culture"].ToString();
            return culture == "en" || culture == "he";
        }
    }


    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            //{
            //    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            //    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            //    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            //});

            var connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ConnStr"];
            //@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=IDC.GetPassSystem.DB;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
            services.AddDbContext<CarEnteranceContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(
                LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                opts =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                            new CultureInfo("he-IL"),
                    };

                    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("he-IL");
                    // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    // UI strings that we have localized.
                    opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                    opts.RequestCultureProviders = new[]{ new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider{
                                IndexOfCulture=1,
                                IndexofUICulture=1
                            }};
                    //opts.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
                    //{
                    //    // My custom request culture logic
                    //    return new ProviderCultureResult("he-IL");
                    //}));

                });

            services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>());
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            //services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddKendo();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                //app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                //routes.MapRoute(
                //        name: "default",
                //        template: "{controller=CarEnteranceRequests}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "LocalizedDefault",
                        template: "{culture:culture}/{controller=CarEnteranceRequests}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "CatchAll",
                     //template: "{culture:culture}/{controller=CarEnteranceRequests}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                     template: "{*catchall}",
                      defaults: new { controller = "CarEnteranceRequests", action = "RedirectToDefaultCulture", culture = "he" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\GatePassSystem.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: aa6e8352-12f8-4e41-8d73-bcb66aefada8-->
```

Comment: What page is the redirect sending them to?

Comment: Is Forms Authentication enabled in IIS (it would be defined in web.config, or you can view it in IIS Manager)